# sails-permissions blacklist read criteria

Tags: sails.js

I have a model with a payment ID, and when I do a GET request it returns the blacklisted item

```
WorkOrder.create({
          id: 1,
          requestedDate: new Date(),
          user: user[0],
          product: product[0],
          paid: true,
          paymentID: 'abcd12'
        })
```

When I do a simple get call to /workOrder/1

```
        it('should not return the paymentID to the registered user', function(){
            return request
                .get('/workOrder/1')
                .expect(200)
                .then(function(res){
                    console.log(res.body)
                    return expect(res.body.paymentID).to.equal(undefined)
                })
        })
```

It returns the paymentID with the payload

```
{ user: 322,                                                                                                                                                                       
  product: 733,                                                                                                                                                                    
  id: 1,                                                                                                                                                                           
  requestedDate: '2016-11-06T15:04:41.174Z',                                                                                       
  paid: true,                                                                                                                                                                      
  paymentID: 'abcd12',                                                                                                                                                             
  createdAt: '2016-11-06T15:04:41.179Z',                                                                                                                                           
  updatedAt: '2016-11-06T15:04:41.179Z' }
```

even though in bootstrap.js I have

```
  ok = ok.then(function(){
    return PermissionService.grant({
      role: 'registered',
      model: 'WorkOrder',
      action: 'read',
      criteria: {blacklist: ['paymentID']}
    })
  })
```

and in criteria

sails> Criteria.find({}).then(function(r) {console.log(r)})

```
Promise {                                                                                                                                                                          
  _bitField: 0,                                                                                                                                                                    
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,                                                                                                                                                 
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,                                                                                                                                                   
  _promise0: undefined,                                                                                                                                                            
  _receiver0: undefined }                                                                                                                                                          
sails> [                                                                                                                                                                      
  { permission: 11953,                                                                                                                                                             
    blacklist: [ 'paymentID' ],                                                                                                                                                    
    createdAt: '2016-11-06T15:11:52.648Z',                                                                                                                                         
    updatedAt: '2016-11-06T15:11:52.648Z',                                                                                                                                         
    id: 46 } ]
```

and in permissions

sails> Permission.find({id: 11953}).populate('model').populate('role').then(function(r){console.log(r)})

```
Promise {                                                                                                                                                                          
  _bitField: 0,                                                                                                                                                                    
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,                                                                                                                                                 
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,                                                                                                                                                   
  _promise0: undefined,                                                                                                                                                            
  _receiver0: undefined }                                                                                                                                                          
sails> [ { model:                                                                                                                                                                  
     { name: 'WorkOrder',                                                                                                                                                          
       identity: 'workorder',                                                                                                                                                      
       attributes:                                                                                                                                                                 
            ...                                                                                                                                        
       id: 2029 },                                                                                                                                                                 
    role:                                                                                                                                                                          
     { name: 'registered',                                                                                                                                                         
       active: true,                                                                                                                                                               
       createdAt: '2016-11-06T15:11:51.522Z',                                                                                                                                      
       updatedAt: '2016-11-06T15:11:51.522Z',                                                                                                                                      
       id: 572 },                                                                                                                                                                  
    action: 'read',                                                                                                                                                                
    relation: 'role',                                                                                                                                                              
    createdAt: '2016-11-06T15:11:52.640Z',                                                                                                                                         
    updatedAt: '2016-11-06T15:11:52.642Z',                                                                                                                                         
    id: 11953 } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `WorkOrder` model, add this `toJSON` function near the end of the file (still inside the `module.exports`). Basically what it does is that before the model ever gets parsed into JSON, it removes the `paymentID`

```
// Remove the password when sending data to JSON
toJSON: function() {
  var obj = this.toObject();
  delete obj.paymentID;
  return obj;
},
```

[This link to the Sails Docs](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/records/to-json) explains the concept in further detail along with more examples.

Comment: This won't quite work for me, as I have some roles that need to see the paymentID.  If need be, I can do this in the controller before I send the response back based on role, but `sails-permissions` is supposed to take care of it for me.  I'll still upvote as a possible (although not best) solution.